# KVC - about data type

Tags: objective-c, ios

this is the code:

```
NSNumber *taskId = [[self.taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"identity"];    
NSInteger *intTaskId = [[self.taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"identity"];
```

`self.taskList` is an `NSArray` which filled with core data fetch request in ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method. 
the `taskId` is: 1
the `intTaskId` is: 269303816
In actually, the value stored in core data is: 1

below is my questions:
1, I am confused why the `NSInteger` incorrect? 
2, Should I have to replace `NSInteger` with `NSNumber` to avoid any other problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSNumber` is an object, whereas `NSInteger` is simply a `typedef` for a primitive (non-object) type (like `int`). `NSInteger` is *not* a subclass of `NSNumber`. Core Data returns numbers as instances of `NSNumber`. You're getting the weird `NSInteger` value because it's pointing to an object of type `NSNumber` but attempting to print it as if it were just an integer.

You'll need to replace `NSInteger` with `NSNumber` to avoid any problems. You could also use the `intValue` method on `NSNumber` to get back an `NSInteger`:

```
NSNumber *objTaskId = [[self.taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"identity"];
NSInteger *intTaskId = [objTaskId intValue];
```

You'll need to do this if you want to do comparisons (greater than, equal too, smaller than) or arithmetic (you can't add an `NSNumber` to another `NSNumber` or an `NSNumber` to a primitive type like an `int` or `float`).

Comment: not always int:

    #if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
    typedef long NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
    #else
    typedef int NSInteger;
    typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
    #endif

Comment: (sorry for the bad formatting, code is not preformatted in comments as in answers)

Comment: big thanks both of you, now I have an idea about how to use NSNumber and NSInteger.

Comment: @cdelacroix thanks, I'll change the wording to "primitive type" accordingly. Also, I believe you can format code blocks using back-ticks: `Here is some code`. @rock you're welcome!

Comment: @rock if you appreciated the answer, please mark it as correct using the outline of the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: @JackLawrence: yes about back-ticks, but it does not allow multi-lines code blocks, thus making it useless which `#define` statements.